# RAM / Addresses

Tags: cpu, ram, memory-address

A machine has 4GB RAM and the processor is 32 bits. The large screen (monitor) needs atleast 2^21 addresses and the machine already supports one screen with 1280x800 resolution which is equivalent to needing 1,024,000 addresses. The address space for a few other peripherals take at least another 2^21 addresses.

If you want all of the 4GB of RAM and all the peripheralds above including the large screen monitor to be accessible, how much bigger does the address bus need to be?

I am completely stuck on this question, if anyone can offer help that would be fantastic.

I look forward to hearing from anyone.

Comment: does the machine has mmu? If yes, you don't need to have bigger address space.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer.  I made a "C" in computer architecture class in both undergrad and grad school. So take this answer with a grain of salt.

For reference:

```
2^21 is 2MB
2^20 is 1MB
2^32 is 4GB == 4096 MB
```

The large screen monitor needs 2MB.  The other 1280x800 monitor needs 1MB.  The peripheral address space is also 2MB  So that's 5MB total for all displays and devices.

So the total address space is 4096 MB + 5MB == 4101 MB

Expanding out 4101 MB is:

```
4101 * 1024 * 1024 = 4300210176
```

So the valid address ranges are from 0..4300210175 (subtract 1 since "0" is a valid address)

4300210175 is the following in binary:

```
100000000010011111111111111111111
```

That's an address space that is 33 bits wide

Assuming the original address bus is 32 bits, the new one needs to grow by 1. That extra bit to the address space plenty of space for the existing peripherals and room to add more devices.

I suppose intuitively, if every new address line doubles the address space of the previous set, then deducing "1" as the answer is obvious.

Either I'm a late bloomer, or you can see why I didn't do so well in the architecture class.

Comment: So the address bus needs to be 1 bit larger? Is it just 2^33 - 2^32?

Comment: Correct. You are growing from 2^32 to 2^33.

Comment: Meaning that it needs a 4GB bigger address bus am I right? By the way, I really appreciate the prompt responses and your help. Thank you Selbie!

Comment: Are you right? I don't know. I made in "C" in this class.  And that was a long time ago. :)

Comment: Is the 1280x800 monitor 256 shades of grey or color? 1280*800=1024000 so 1 megabyte allocates only 1 byte per pixel (color takes 3 bytes per pixel.)

Comment: If the address space of the monitors were 3x bigger, would it change the answer? ;)

Comment: It does not specify, it's just a 1200X800 resolution screen (which translates to needing 1,024,000 addresses)

Comment: Wait, is it supposed to be 2^32 bits or bytes? Getting confused with the terminology.

Thanks, I hope one of you experts can respond!

Comment: Bytes. Memory addresses are always in bytes. (Or technically in the addressing scheme of the CPU and architecture, but there's realistically never an addressing scheme that addresses to the bit).